# Como leer con pyspark ficheros en databricks desde DBFS que han sido dejado como resultado de una ejecución anterior

Tags: apache-spark, nlp, pyspark, databricks, spark

Tengo un par de notebooks en databricks el **notebook1** para el tratamiento de textos (tokenizar, borrar stopwords...) que da como salida un fichero de texto limpio. El **notebook2**, lee el texto limpio y realiza un análisis de sentimientos.

Añado una vista del esquema de salida del dataframe de **notebook1**:

```
cleanDF.printSchema

Out[25]: <bound method DataFrame.printSchema of DataFrame[ID: string, Year: int, TypeComment: string, NewText: string, ExecutionName: string, ExecutionTime: string]>
```

Y el dataframe de salida de **notebook1**, tiene esta pinta:

```
+------------------+----+-----------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+
|                ID|Year|TypeComment|             NewText|   ExecutionName|       ExecutionTime|
+------------------+----+-----------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+
|aaaaaaaaaaaaadWUAQ|2020|    General|limpieza general....|TextPretreatment|2020-08-10 08:28:...|
|aaaaaaaaaaaaae2UAA|2020|    General|    todo correcto...|TextPretreatment|2020-08-10 08:28:...|
|aaaaaaaaaaaaaxUUAQ|2020|    General|            correcto|TextPretreatment|2020-08-10 08:28:...|
|aaaaaaaaaaaaaEJUAY|2020|    General|                bien|TextPretreatment|2020-08-10 08:28:...|
|a0aaaaaaaaaaaaaUAQ|2020|    General|rocio ventas trad...|TextPretreatment|2020-08-10 08:28:...|
+------------------+----+-----------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

En local, para generar el fichero de salida uso esta instrucción, que me genera un único csv con el nombre del fichero indicado:

```
cleanDF.toPandas().to_csv("./Test/Outputs/TextPre-treatment.csv", header=True)
```

En local, todo funciona correctamente, porque tengo las rutas de mi maquina para Inputs y Outputs en cada notebook. Sin embargo, al pasarlo a **Databricks**, tengo problemas al intentar ejecutar el **notebook2**, ya que su fichero de entrada es la salida del **notebook1**, que a escribirse en DBFS genera diferentes directorios.

Revisando algunas publicaciones como [write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv) y [save-content-of-spark-dataframe-as-a-single-csv-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967687/save-content-of-spark-dataframe-as-a-single-csv-file/43389432), en databricks he reemplazado la línea de generación de ficheros y estoy usando este es el código con el que almaceno mi dataframe de salida de **notebook1** en DBFS:

```
dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Test/Outputs/Pretreatment/TextPre-treatment.csv", True)

cleanDF.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Test/Outputs/Pretreatment/TextPre-treatment.csv")
```

También he intentado con esta alternativa:

```
cleanDF.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Test/Outputs/Pretreatment/TextPre-treatment.csv")
```

En ambos casos almacena un solo fichero con los resultados (porque mi fichero de salida no es de gran tamaño), pero genera la siguiente ruta y ficheros:

[image: ruta y directorios de salida de notebook1]

El problema viene cuando ejecuto **notebook2** e intento leer de esa ruta, el output de **notebook1**. Ya que no puedo dar un nombre específico de fichero, porque el nombre va cambiando después de cada ejecución. **En notebook2** hago esto:

```
pathText= "/FileStore/tables/Test/Outputs/Pretreatment/TextPre-treatment.csv"

schema = StructType([
    StructField("Index", StringType()),
    StructField("ID", StringType()),
    StructField("Year", IntegerType()),
    StructField("TypeComment", StringType()),
    StructField("NewText", StringType()),
    StructField("ExecutionName", StringType()),
    StructField("ExecutionTime", StringType())
    ])
df= spark.read.csv(pathText, schema=schema , header=True)
df.show(5)
```

Aparentemente lee el fichero, pero trae todo a nulo:

```
+-----+----+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+
|Index|  ID|Year|TypeComment|NewText|ExecutionName|ExecutionTime|
+-----+----+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| null|null|null|       null|   null|         null|         null|
| null|null|null|       null|   null|         null|         null|
| null|null|null|       null|   null|         null|         null|
| null|null|null|       null|   null|         null|         null|
| null|null|null|       null|   null|         null|         null|
+-----+----+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Si reviso el contenido del fichero `part-00000-tid-*.csv` en DBFS, si tiene contenido:
[image: preview del fichero de salida notebook1]

Me gustaría saber como consigo que **notebook2** pueda leer correctamente el fichero de salida de **notebook1** (sea uno o varios) y si existe una forma más apropiada de hacer este tipo de lectura de ficheros, cuando en **databricks** la entrada de un notebook depende de la salida de otro.

Mi configuración es:

```
Spark NLP version:  2.5.5
Apache Spark version:  2.4.5
Databricks Runtime:  6.5.x-cpu-ml-scala2.11
```

Comment: Podes poner un printSchema del primer archivo antes de grabarlo? O sea de este: cleanDF. También un Show de algunos datos de cleanDF así lo pruebo de manera local.

Comment: Hola @jqc, he editado la pregunta para añadir el esquema y un show del dataframe de salida de **notebook1**, para ver su estructura antes de enviarlo al fichero. Como indicaba en la publicación, en mis ejecuciones en local no tengo este problema porque genero un único fichero csv de salida con `cleanDF.toPandas().to_csv("./Test/Outputs/TextPre-treatment.csv", header=True)`, pero esto no funciona en databricks (aunque use la ruta de DBFS).

Comment: Es verdad, no tiene problemas en local. Yo probaría quitando el index. Porque se me hace que es un error en la definción del schema. Porque vos tenés el mismo problema que se ve en esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157775/null-values-when-trying-to-import-csv-in-azure-databricks-dbfs

Comment: Efectivamente @jqc, lo estaba revisando esta mañana después de tu comentario. He detectado que al cambiar la columna que convertía en pandas dataframe  no se genera la columna con el indice en el fichero en DBFS. He ajustado el esquema antes de leer y me ha funcionado bien la lectura en databricks para el notebook2.

Comment: Genial. Lo pongo en la respuesta así queda como aceptada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo probaría quitando el index. Porque se me hace que es un error en la definción del schema. Me parece que vos tenés el mismo problema que se ve en esta pregunta: [NULL values when trying to import CSV in Azure Databricks DBFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157775/null-values-when-trying-to-import-csv-in-azure-databricks-dbfs)